# JAXB marshaller no-arg default constructor

Tags: java, jaxb

I would like to marshalling a java object from a java library.

When marshalling a java object using JAXB marschaller, I have got a problem:

> class A does not have a no-arg default constructor

I used a Java Decomplier to check the class a implementation, it is like this:

```
public final class AImpl
  implements A
```

That means I can not extends class `AImpl`.

So How can I fix the problem with no-arg default constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`XmlAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) for this use case.  For an example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Answer (score 1):

How do you know values that should be passed to that constructor then?

I think you will need to override Binder class to unmarshall objects by yourself.